# Deriving a boundary for a single cluster data

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, decision-boundary

### Summary

I have a dataset of 2D points that exhibit a distinct pattern. My goal is to create a boundary that encompasses the main cluster of points while excluding outliers. In other words, if a point isn't within this boundary, then the point is considered to be unrelated to the observed points. What is the best method, or model to derive this boundary?

### Example approach

One approach I've considered is defining a grid of negative clusters or a background mask, followed by applying a clustering algorithm. However, I'm interested in exploring alternative methods that might provide more accurate results.

### Main question

What are the most suitable methods or models for automatically deriving a boundary that encompasses the main cluster of 2D data while ignoring outliers?

### Notes

In the figure below I used some generated data and drew the boundary by hand. I'd prefer the model to be able to derive a similar boundary.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, here's my approach to the problem and how I solved it. It more or less includes 5 steps. If you think a more straightforward approach can be used, please let me know.

```
# Inputs
frontier_data = pd.read_csv(frontier_url)
feature_meshgrid = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(frontier_data[f].min(), frontier_data[f].max(), 0.01) for f in frontier_data])
mesh_table = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(frontier_data.columns, [f.ravel() for f in feature_meshgrid])))

# 1) Fit an outlier detection model to the data
lof = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20, algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30,
                         contamination='auto', metric='minkowski', p=2,
                         novelty=True).fit(frontier_data.to_numpy())
mesh_pred = lof.predict(mesh_table).reshape(feature_meshgrid[0].shape)
cluster = pd.Series(lof.predict(frontier_data), name='cluster')

# 2) Use a smoothing function to smooth out the decision boundary
mesh_threshold_smoothed_pred = threshold_local(mesh_pred, block_size=11)

# 3) Derive the boundary points
bounds = pd.Series((1-np.abs(mesh_threshold_smoothed_pred)).ravel(), name='bounds')
mesh_boundary = mesh_table[bounds >= 0.6].reset_index(drop=True).copy()

# 4) Fit a DBSCAN (clustering) model to separate the points for each line
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=0.1, min_samples=5).fit(mesh_boundary)
mesh_boundary['clusters'] = dbscan.labels_

# 5) Fit a polynomial to each set of points
equations = mesh_boundary.groupby('clusters').apply(lambda x: polynomial_equation(poly_fit(x['y'], x['x'])[1].coef_[::-1]))
equations = equations.rename('equations')
boundary_pred = mesh_boundary.groupby('clusters').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(poly_fit(x['y'], x['x'])[0],
                                                                            name='pred_x', index=x['y']))
boundary_pred = boundary_pred.drop_duplicates()
boundary_pred = pd.merge(mesh_boundary, boundary_pred, on=['clusters', 'y'], how='left')
boundary_pred = pd.merge(boundary_pred, equations, how='left', on='clusters')
```

You can see the end result in the figure below.[image]